# Get all the collection in document

Tags: spring-cloud-gcp

I have following structure in firebase data

Orders -> OrderID -> LocationHistory -> LocationHistoryID -> FieldsData

Orders and LocationHistory are constant whereas OrderID ,LocationHistoryID are document ID

I want to know if  it is possible to generate a query to get all LocationHistory of an order in repository which extends FirestoreReactiveRepository 
in rest it whould be  /Orders/10002/LocationHistory/

Belwo is the code i am currently using

```
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.firestore.Document;

import com.google.cloud.firestore.annotation.DocumentId;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.annotation.PropertyName;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Setter
@Getter
@Document(collectionName = "Orders/10002/LocationHistory")
public class LocationHistory
{
    @DocumentId
    private String id;

    private String lat;

    @PropertyName("long")
    private String longitude;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `LocationHistory` is a sub-collection of the `Orders`, you should retrieve the `Order` which will contain the `LocationHistory`.

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@Document(collectionName = "Orders")
public class Order
{
    @DocumentId
    private String id;

    private List<LocationHistory> locationHistory;
}

@Setter
@Getter
public class LocationHistory
{
    @DocumentId
    private String id;

    private String lat;

    @PropertyName("long")
    private String longitude;

}
```

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411568/mapping-firestore-collection-to-json for details i have attached images there

Comment: I added an example mapping. I hope this helps.

Comment: i get  java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present when querying by id

Comment: This might be because I missed `@DocumentId` on `LocationHistory`. Please try again.

Comment: still getting same error i created a repo https://github.com/haiderali22/spring-firebase-query-app

Comment: i tried to get collection from Firestore instance from findByIDFireStorefunction in service and its working fine

Comment: did u had a chance to see the gihub repo is there any other way to do this?

Comment: `orderRepository.findAllLocationHistoryByOrderID(id)` doesn't really make sense because it's an order repository not a `LocationHistory` repository.

Comment: Have you tried `orderRepository.findById(orderId)`? Then simply access the location history by calling `order.getLocationHistory()`.

Comment: i tried orderRepository.findById(orderId) i get java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present